# Dinamically add channel to existing network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is it possible to dinamically add a new channel to the profile on an existing network ?

On my research I checked that it was possible to update the organizations, policies and chaincodes, but it seems that after the network creation is impossible to add new channels.

If it's possible, what is the process for adding a new channel to the existing profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create a new channel. You just need to create the genesis block for the channel using `configtxgen -profile <nameofProfile> -outputCreateChannelTx channel-artifacts/$CHANNEL_NAME.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME` where name of profile comes from a configtx.yml file. Then create the channel and join the organizations to it.